# FLUTTER - Dynamic string in tab name based on content length in tab body

Tags: flutter, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Hi all I am trying to update Tab name with the number of items in lists stored in tab content. The list is fetched in tab content component. How can I pass list length variable to tab title ?

```
// PARENT WIDGET

    class EventsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventsScreen> createState() => _EventsScreenState();
}

class _EventsScreenState extends State<EventsScreen> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Parent(
      child: TabbedHeader(
        tabTitles: [
          'Žiadosti (HERE I WANT TO ADD LENGTH OF REQUESTS LIST)'
        ],
        title: 'Udalosti',
        tabContents: [
          EventRequestTab() // CHILD COMPONENT WITH LIST OF REQUESTS
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CHILD WIDGET WITH REQUESTS LIST

class EventRequestTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventRequestTab({Key? key, this.requests}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventRequestTab> createState() => _EventRequestState();
}

class _EventRequestState extends State<EventRequestTab> {
  late EventService _eventService;
  late List<EventRequest>? requests;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _eventService = EventService();
    requests = // FETCHING LIST OF REQUESTS

  }
} ... build method etc ....
```

In child widget in initState I am fetching list of requests which is later displayed in ListView. But I dont know how to pass length of fetched list to tabTitles property of TabbedHeader. TabbedHeader is my custom wrapper for TabBar widget.

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: The code is pretty complicated but the point is that widget  which is holding tabs with their names is parent for widget which holds the list ...so the key point of the problem is to find out how to transfer variable from child to parent widget

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele I added the code...hope it helps you

Comment: @Hreso, I added an answer with an update to the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the list fetched in the `initState` of your `EventRequestTab`'s state class by passing a callback into the `EventRequestTab` widget.
This callback will return the list fetched as its parameter and in the `EventsScreen`, the tab name is updated with the length of the list

Here's an update to your code:

```dart
// PARENT WIDGET

class EventsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventsScreen> createState() => _EventsScreenState();
}

class _EventsScreenState extends State<EventsScreen> {
  int? lengthOfRequestList; 


  void updateTabName(List<EventRequest> listOfRequests) {
    setState(() {
      lengthOfRequestList = listOfRequests.length;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Parent(
      child: TabbedHeader(
        tabTitles: ['Žiadosti (${int == null ? '...' : int})'],
        title: 'Udalosti',
        tabContents: [
          EventRequestTab(
            onListFetched: updateTabName,
          ) // CHILD COMPONENT WITH LIST OF REQUESTS
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CHILD WIDGET WITH REQUESTS LIST

class EventRequestTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(List<EventRequest> fetchedList) onListFetched; 
  const EventRequestTab({Key? key, required this.onListFetched}) : super(key: key); 

  @override
  State<EventRequestTab> createState() => _EventRequestState();
}

class _EventRequestState extends State<EventRequestTab> {
  late EventService _eventService;
  late List<EventRequest>? requests;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _eventService = EventService();
    requests = // FETCHING LIST OF REQUESTS
        widget.onListFetched(requests); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know if it works

Comment: Bro it works on 100%. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know @Hreso